# Could not load file or assembly 'sapnco_utils.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: vb.net

Someone knows how to fix this. I did all of these things

1. I cleaned up Temporal files. Win + R
2. I cleaned up Temporal file from C:\Windows...\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
3. I removed the dll and added again
4. I changed the app pool option: Enable 32 bits is true.
5. I changed the option: Load User Profile is now true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check this link 
http://www.dataxstream.com/2012/10/nco-3-0-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-sapnco_utils-dll-or-one-of-its-dependencies/

Only you need to install

- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Pack (x86) (mscvp100.dll)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Pack (x64) (mscvp100.dll)